# How can I test if a set amount of Bitcoin has been received by a given address in Python?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, bitcoin

I am working on a Raspberry Pi powered Bitcoin vending machine and I am having trouble finding a Python lib and syntax that I can use. Does anyone have any ideas about how I could set up the Raspberry Pi constantly testing if a given address has received a certain amount of Bitcoin.

ie. If someone sent 1 mBTC to the address 1FcD1cqXfqherG3VF3CFwBAVrZ2XrC4sWo it would return true, or run a different subroutine.

Answer (score -1):

I think blockchain.info is a good idea. They have an API also.